# how to retrieve data from local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a register form using javascript from which data is getting stored in the local storage,but I want to retrieve data from local storage for login purpose, following is my controller.js-

```
//Storing data from local storage into an array of objects
 var usersdata = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('key_users' ) );
function validatelogin()
{
    usersdata = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('key_users' ) );
    var usernameinput   = document.getElementById("username");
    var passwordinput   = document.getElementById("password");
    for(var p in userdata)
    {
      console.log(p+':'+userdata[p].username+'|'+userdata[p].email);
      if(usernameinput==userdata[p].username && passwordinput==userdata[p].password)
      {
         alert("Logged in successfully");
      }
    }
}
```

While trying to login, its giving error called 'userdata' is not defined..Please help with whats wrong in the code?

Comment: You already know it `localStorage.getItem`

Comment: There is variable name difference in your code usersdata != userdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop change `userdata` to `usersdata`

Answer (score 4):

You can easily retrieve data using

```
var myData = localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage');
```

But before you even do that you should set the localstorage first

```
localStorage.setItem('myDataStorage', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

and then you retrieve from the same local storage using getItem and then specifying the name of the created localStorage item.

Comment: At the time of retrieval need to use JSON.parse()

**JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage')))**