# Get data from Local Storage

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I've the following data in my local storage:

```
[{
  "event": "addToCart",
  "eventLabel": "Test Product",
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "add": {
      "products": [{
        "name": "Test Product",
        "id": "78789",
        "price": "429.00",
        "category": "Catalog Page",
        "list": "Massage\/Massage Chairs\/Portable Massage Chairs",
        "quantity": "1"
      }]
    }
  }
}]
```

and I need to access to the value of `ecommerce`. So obtaining the following data:

```
"ecommerce": {
  "currencyCode": "USD",
  "add": {
    "products": [{
      "name": "Test Product",
      "id": "78789",
      "price": "429.00",
      "category": "Catalog Page",
      "list": "Massage\/Massage Chairs\/Portable Massage Chairs",
      "quantity": "1"
    }]
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to retrieve data from local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219531/how-to-retrieve-data-from-local-storage)

Comment: No I'm able to get local storage but I don't know how to create array as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the json you have

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

then you can access any data key and values like this:

```
var ecom = data.ecommerce
```